# How to check if product is added to wishlist from 'list page' or 'product page'

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, wishlist

I am wondering if there is any way to know that product is added to the wishlist from 'Category/List' page OR 'Product View' page. I need this only when product is successfully added to the wishlist. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own observer that catches a magento event.

Here is the [event cheat sheet](https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-8/) , and here is a tutorial by inchoo on [how to write an observer](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-event-driven-programming-tips-tricks/).

You can observe `wishlist_add_product` and check for the referer url.

See how to [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282137/how-to-get-the-original-referrer-url-on-success-page)

Comment: In this case it will always return you login page url as referral url if a customer try to add without login. As I mentioned earlier - "I need this only when product is successfully added to the wishlist".